# How to prevent systemd to stop a service on reboot

Tags: systemd, services, reboot

I have the following service file which is used to turn on and off an external device:

```
[Unit]
Description=Manage the UR controller, turn it off when the system goes down.
Requires=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/ur_boot
ExecStop=/usr/local/sbin/ur_shutdown

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It works well, but the external device is long to boot and shut down, so when I reboot, it takes a while to be ready again.

Is it possible to tell systemd to not stop my service when I do a reboot, but still stop it for a regular shutdown?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is too long for a comment.  But I hope it will point you in a good direction.

From `man systemd.special`:

```
   shutdown.target
       A special target unit that terminates the services on system shutdown.

       Services that shall be terminated on system shutdown shall add Conflicts= 
       and Before= dependencies to this unit for their service unit, which is 
       implicitly done when DefaultDependencies=yes is set (the default).
```

All services implicitly `Conflicts=` with `shutdown.target`.  So when `shutdown.target` is raised, all services will stop.  The only exception is if you add `DefaultDependencies=no`.

In comments of the other answer, you ask about `reboot.target`.

```
   reboot.target
       A special target unit for shutting down and rebooting the system.
```

If we look into the details of `reboot.target` we can see it raises `shutdown.target` via `systemd1-reboot.service`:

```
$ busctl introspect \
    org.freedesktop.systemd1 \
    /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/reboot_2etarget
...
.Names    "reboot.target" "runlevel6.target" "ctrl-alt-del.target"
.Requires "systemd-reboot.service"

$ busctl introspect \
    org.freedesktop.systemd1 \
    /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/systemd_2dreboot_2eservice
...
.DefaultDependencies false
.After               "final.target" "system.slice" "umount.target" "shutdown.target" "systemd-journald.socket"
.Requires            "final.target" "system.slice" "umount.target" "shutdown.target"
.SuccessAction       "reboot-force"
```

---

So in your case, you could add `DefaultDependencies=no` to the `[Unit]` section avoid stopping your service when rebooting, but it will also fail to stop your service during shutdown.  That's because a reboot includes a shutdown.

---

My best idea (not sure if it will work) is to create a service with:

```
[Unit]
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=reboot.target shutdown.target

[Service]
ExecStart=touch %t/rebooting

[Install]
WantedBy=reboot.target
```

This will create a file in ram when a reboot is initiated.

Then change your service to:

```
ExecStop=/bin/bash -c "test -e %t/rebooting || /usr/local/sbin/ur_shutdown"
```

This will prevent your `ExecStop` command from running when that file exists.  This doesn't stop your `ExecStart` command from running, but I would hope that if your peripheral is already running, this will just return immediately.

If you need to avoid running `ExecStart`, then try creating the file in a non-volatile location.

```
ExecStart=touch %S/rebooting
```

and then only running your script if it doesn't exist (and cleaning it up if it does exist).

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "if [ -e %S/rebooting ]; then rm %S/rebooting; else /usr/local/sbin/ur_start; fi"
ExecStop=/bin/bash -c "test -e %S/rebooting || /usr/local/sbin/ur_shutdown"
```

Answer (score 0):

For Linux (thus systemd) there is no difference between shutting the computer down or restarting it (except for the fact that one state ends with a stop of the computer and the other start the computer again, it is important to note that no operating system is running when we reach those states). So no, you can not keep anything running when rebooting (remember, the computer comes down).

Do not be confused with hybernation, it brings the system to a stop keeping a copy of the machine's status (caching memory to disk) and being able to recover the system to the state it was before shutting it down.

In your case, if your system takes too long to boot and you have identified the device that delays it, you may want to check which other services depend on this device, you might be able to eliminate the dependency if you don't consider it important so that the startup can continue while that device starts.

Comment: Since there are multiple systems targets (reboot.target, halt.target) I was hoping there was a way to trigger the stop only in one of these.

Comment: You might have wrongly understood my setup: I know the computer will be turned off, but it doesn't mean the service will be "stopped": it is a oneshot service, which will simply send a message on the network to shut down the external device.

Comment: It does mean the service is stopped, unless you have another meaning for "service". For me (it doesn't mean I am correct about this) a service is a daemon running in the system that provides... well a service like an sftp server, cron, email, etc... I can only see a reason for what you state in cases like HDs, there might be instructions sent by the service to the drive when the system comes down so that the heads are parked or the drive stops spinning or whatever, so what is the device that is taking so long to boot? If you unplug it before shutdown and after startup does it work?

Comment: The device is a robot controller (another computer). "service" is the term in systemd, but there is no Daemon as it is a "oneshot" type service (it is a command that runs for 1s at start and another at stop). Unplugging the ethernet cable beforehand shutting down does indeed prevent the robot controller to receive the shutdown command.

Comment: I didn't dig into systemctl that much, so there might be (or not) an option for the reboot, but you may be able to modify `ur_shutdown` so that it checks if the system is in the init level for restart (level 6 when running `runlevel` command) and only shut down the robot controller in that case.

Comment: I'm not sure the runlevel will be available, and how, but thanks for the idea!

Comment: Check this out: https://www.ostechnix.com/check-runlevel-linux/